# How to Stop an Endless String in R

Tags: r, arguments

I'm new to R Programming and have somehow gotten stuck in an argument that will not stop.  I wrote view(file) and hit enter and now there is an endless string of "+" and the argument will not close.  Any help would be appreciated on how to close my argument.  I know I can just force quit the program, but I would rather just figure out of to end the argument.  Thank You!

Comment: literally, `view(file)` should give an error ('could not find function "view"'). This is one of those cases where a screen shot might actually be helpful.

Comment: Hit the escape-key and start over.

Answer (score 6):

In `R`, if you keep seeing an endless string of `+`, it means that you didn't close a pair of either single quotes `''`, double quotes `""`, or parentheses/brackets `()`/`{}`.

Usually, not closing a pair of parentheses or brackets produces an error sooner or later. But open quotes can keep going forever if you do not close them (or unless you terminate the command: `esc` in RStudio or `ctrl+c` if in command line).

Here is an example:

```
> view("file
+ i can keep
+ writing
+ until
+ i close the
+ double quote
+ , but once I do,
+ I have to also close the parentheses )
+ "
+ )
Error: could not find function "view"
>
```

Comment: Wonderful, the esc worked and I appreciate knowing what I did wrong so that it doesn't happen again.  Thank you so much!!